# What does work mean here?

Tags: meaning

I have seen an article regarding whether should we exercise first thing in morning or not and I came across a sentence which seems a little odd to understand.

> Early morning exercise can be bad for your health, say researchers.
>
> They claim the body's immune system is not ready to cope with intense
>   exercise first thing in the morning.
>
> A pre-breakfast work-out puts the exerciser at greater risk of
>   infection than the same level **of exertion after work**, the study by
>   sports scientists suggests.

([Source](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-130553/Dawn-work-harm.html))

What does "work" mean here?

Comment: It's best to include a link to the source, so folks can refer to it. In this case, "work" appears to mean "the job you have in the day". This is because the article says more than once that evening is the best time to exercise, and since most people work approximately 9 to 5, *after work* means after your work day, or in the evening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Work" here assumes the reader is engaged in some sort of daily routine which involves waking up, eating breakfast, then performing some sort of job function for a significant amount of time.

For the purposes of this sentence you could replace "after work" with "in the evening."

Answer (score 2):

here work means daily activities (job) of the person.They are trying to say that exercise after coming back from office is less risky and better than early morning exercise.